# How to scrape specific tables from web page with multiple tables?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some NFL data from:

`url =  https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/opp.htm.`

I first tried to scrape the data from the tables with pandas. I've done this before and it's always been straight forward. I expected pandas to return a list of all tables found on the page. However, when I ran
`dfs = pd.read_html(url)`
I only received the first two tables from the web page, Team Defense and Team Advanced Defense.

I then went to try to scrape the other tables with bs4 and requests. To test, I first only tried to scrape the first table:

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', id = 'advanced_defense')

rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I was then able to simply change the `id` such that I returned both the Team Defense and Team Advanced Defense - the same two tables that pandas returned.

However, when I try to use the same method to scrape the other tables on the page I receive an error. I obtained the `id` by inspecting the web page in the same manner as the first two tables and am unable to get a result.

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', id = 'passing')

rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

It is not able to find anything for `table` when attempting to scrape any of the other tables on the page as I receive the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I find it strange how both pandas and bs4 are only able to return the Team Defense and Team Advanced Defense tables.

I only intend to scrape the Team Defense, Passing Defense, and Rushing Defense tables.

How could I approach successfully scraping the Passing Defense and Rushing Defense tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the sports reference.com sites are tricky in that the first table (or a few tables) do show up in the html source. The other tables are dynamically rendered. HOWEVER, those other tables are within the Comments within the html. So to get those other tables, you have to pull out the comments, then can use pandas or beautifulsoup to get those table tags.

So you can grab the team stats as you normally would. Then pull the comments and parse those other tables.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url =  'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/opp.htm'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

dfs = [pd.read_html(url, header=0, attrs={'id':'team_stats'})[0]]
dfs[0].columns = dfs[0].iloc[0,:]
dfs[0] = dfs[0].iloc[1:,:].reset_index(drop=True)

for each in comments:
    if 'table' in each and ('id="passing"' in each or 'id="rushing"' in each):
        dfs.append(pd.read_html(each)[0])
```

**Output:**

```
for df in dfs:
    print (df)


0    Rk                    Tm    G     PF  ... 1stPy   Sc%   TO%      EXP
0     1  New England Patriots   16    225  ...    39  19.4  17.3   165.75
1     2         Buffalo Bills   16    259  ...    33  23.6  12.4    39.85
2     3      Baltimore Ravens   16    282  ...    39  32.9  14.6    16.61
3     4         Chicago Bears   16    298  ...    30  31.5  10.7    -4.15
4     5     Minnesota Vikings   16    303  ...    31  34.5  17.0    -7.88
5     6   Pittsburgh Steelers   16    303  ...    30  29.9  19.0    85.78
6     7    Kansas City Chiefs   16    308  ...    39  34.6  13.6   -65.69
7     8   San Francisco 49ers   16    310  ...    30  29.0  14.2    77.41
8     9     Green Bay Packers   16    313  ...    20  34.5  14.1   -63.65
9    10        Denver Broncos   16    316  ...    34  37.3   8.4   -35.98
10   11        Dallas Cowboys   16    321  ...    38  35.5   9.9   -36.81
11   12      Tennessee Titans   16    331  ...    27  32.1  11.8   -54.20
12   13    New Orleans Saints   16    341  ...    43  34.7  12.7   -41.89
13   14  Los Angeles Chargers   16    345  ...    28  37.3   8.2   -86.11
14   15   Philadelphia Eagles   16    354  ...    28  33.9  10.2   -29.57
15   16         New York Jets   16    359  ...    40  34.4  10.1    -0.06
16   17      Los Angeles Rams   16    364  ...    30  33.7  12.7   -11.53
17   18    Indianapolis Colts   16    373  ...    23  39.3  13.1   -58.37
18   19        Houston Texans   16    385  ...    28  39.3  13.1  -160.87
19   20      Cleveland Browns   16    393  ...    37  36.9  11.2   -91.15
20   21  Jacksonville Jaguars   16    397  ...    33  37.4   9.2  -120.09
21   22      Seattle Seahawks   16    398  ...    25  37.1  16.3   -92.02
22   23       Atlanta Falcons   16    399  ...    30  42.8   9.0  -105.34
23   24       Oakland Raiders   16    419  ...    52  41.2   8.5  -159.71
24   25    Cincinnati Bengals   16    420  ...    21  39.8   8.8  -132.66
25   26         Detroit Lions   16    423  ...    39  40.1   9.0  -142.55
26   27   Washington Redskins   16    435  ...    34  41.9  12.2  -135.83
27   28     Arizona Cardinals   16    442  ...    38  42.6   9.5  -174.55
28   29  Tampa Bay Buccaneers   16    449  ...    39  39.6  13.5    12.23
29   30       New York Giants   16    451  ...    32  39.7   8.7  -105.11
30   31     Carolina Panthers   16    470  ...    30  41.4   9.4  -116.88
31   32        Miami Dolphins   16    494  ...    34  45.6   8.8  -175.02
32  NaN              Avg Team  NaN  365.0  ...  32.9  36.0  11.8    -56.6
33  NaN          League Total  NaN  11680  ...  1054  36.0  11.8      NaN
34  NaN              Avg Tm/G  NaN   22.8  ...   2.1  36.0  11.8      NaN

[35 rows x 28 columns]
      Rk                    Tm     G      Cmp  ...  NY/A  ANY/A  Sk%     EXP
0    1.0   San Francisco 49ers  16.0    318.0  ...  4.80    4.6  8.5   58.30
1    2.0  New England Patriots  16.0    303.0  ...  5.00    3.5  8.1  117.74
2    3.0   Pittsburgh Steelers  16.0    314.0  ...  5.50    4.7  9.5   20.19
3    4.0         Buffalo Bills  16.0    348.0  ...  5.20    4.7  7.4   30.01
4    5.0  Los Angeles Chargers  16.0    328.0  ...  6.50    6.3  6.1  -92.16
5    6.0      Baltimore Ravens  16.0    318.0  ...  5.70    5.2  6.4   15.40
6    7.0      Cleveland Browns  16.0    318.0  ...  6.30    6.1  6.9  -64.09
7    8.0    Kansas City Chiefs  16.0    352.0  ...  5.70    5.2  7.2  -36.78
8    9.0         Chicago Bears  16.0    362.0  ...  5.90    5.7  5.3  -47.04
9   10.0        Dallas Cowboys  16.0    370.0  ...  5.90    6.1  6.4  -67.46
10  11.0        Denver Broncos  16.0    348.0  ...  6.30    6.1  6.9  -61.45
11  12.0      Los Angeles Rams  16.0    348.0  ...  5.90    5.7  8.2  -42.76
12  13.0     Carolina Panthers  16.0    347.0  ...  6.20    5.8  8.9  -63.03
13  14.0     Green Bay Packers  16.0    326.0  ...  6.30    5.7  7.0  -27.30
14  15.0     Minnesota Vikings  16.0    394.0  ...  5.80    5.3  7.4  -34.01
15  16.0  Jacksonville Jaguars  16.0    327.0  ...  6.70    6.7  8.3  -98.77
16  17.0         New York Jets  16.0    363.0  ...  6.10    6.0  5.6  -79.16
17  18.0   Washington Redskins  16.0    371.0  ...  6.50    6.7  7.8 -135.17
18  19.0   Philadelphia Eagles  16.0    348.0  ...  6.30    6.4  7.0  -88.15
19  20.0    New Orleans Saints  16.0    371.0  ...  5.90    5.8  7.8  -94.59
20  21.0    Cincinnati Bengals  16.0    308.0  ...  7.40    7.4  5.8 -126.81
21  22.0       Atlanta Falcons  16.0    351.0  ...  6.90    7.0  5.0 -128.75
22  23.0    Indianapolis Colts  16.0    394.0  ...  6.60    6.4  6.8  -86.44
23  24.0      Tennessee Titans  16.0    386.0  ...  6.40    6.2  6.7  -92.39
24  25.0       Oakland Raiders  16.0    337.0  ...  7.40    7.8  5.7 -177.69
25  26.0        Miami Dolphins  16.0    344.0  ...  7.40    7.7  4.0 -172.01
26  27.0      Seattle Seahawks  16.0    383.0  ...  6.70    6.2  4.5  -77.18
27  28.0       New York Giants  16.0    369.0  ...  7.10    7.4  6.1 -152.48
28  29.0        Houston Texans  16.0    375.0  ...  6.90    7.1  5.0 -160.60
29  30.0  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  16.0    408.0  ...  6.10    6.2  6.6  -38.17
30  31.0     Arizona Cardinals  16.0    421.0  ...  7.00    7.7  6.2 -190.81
31  32.0         Detroit Lions  16.0    381.0  ...  7.10    7.7  4.4 -162.94
32   NaN              Avg Team   NaN    354.1  ...  6.29    6.2  6.7  -73.60
33   NaN          League Total   NaN  11331.0  ...  6.29    6.2  6.7     NaN
34   NaN              Avg Tm/G   NaN     22.1  ...  6.29    6.2  6.7     NaN

[35 rows x 25 columns]
      Rk                    Tm     G      Att  ...     TD  Y/A    Y/G    EXP
0    1.0  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  16.0    362.0  ...   11.0  3.3   73.8  56.23
1    2.0         New York Jets  16.0    417.0  ...   12.0  3.3   86.9  72.34
2    3.0   Philadelphia Eagles  16.0    353.0  ...   13.0  4.1   90.1  47.64
3    4.0    New Orleans Saints  16.0    345.0  ...   12.0  4.2   91.3  39.45
4    5.0      Baltimore Ravens  16.0    340.0  ...   12.0  4.4   93.4  -1.25
5    6.0  New England Patriots  16.0    365.0  ...    7.0  4.2   95.5  33.13
6    7.0    Indianapolis Colts  16.0    383.0  ...    8.0  4.1   97.9  21.54
7    8.0       Oakland Raiders  16.0    405.0  ...   15.0  3.9   98.1  17.69
8    9.0         Chicago Bears  16.0    414.0  ...   16.0  3.9  102.0  38.83
9   10.0         Buffalo Bills  16.0    388.0  ...   12.0  4.3  103.1  10.92
10  11.0        Dallas Cowboys  16.0    407.0  ...   14.0  4.1  103.5  25.11
11  12.0      Tennessee Titans  16.0    415.0  ...   14.0  4.0  104.5  28.27
12  13.0     Minnesota Vikings  16.0    404.0  ...    8.0  4.3  108.0  21.01
13  14.0   Pittsburgh Steelers  16.0    462.0  ...    7.0  3.8  109.6  63.09
14  15.0       Atlanta Falcons  16.0    421.0  ...   13.0  4.2  110.9  17.98
15  16.0        Denver Broncos  16.0    426.0  ...    9.0  4.2  111.4  12.72
16  17.0   San Francisco 49ers  16.0    401.0  ...   11.0  4.5  112.6   9.91
17  18.0  Los Angeles Chargers  16.0    429.0  ...   15.0  4.2  112.8   1.08
18  19.0      Los Angeles Rams  16.0    444.0  ...   15.0  4.1  113.1  21.49
19  20.0       New York Giants  16.0    469.0  ...   19.0  3.9  113.3  40.51
20  21.0         Detroit Lions  16.0    455.0  ...   13.0  4.1  115.9  17.32
21  22.0      Seattle Seahawks  16.0    388.0  ...   22.0  4.9  117.7 -17.45
22  23.0     Green Bay Packers  16.0    411.0  ...   15.0  4.7  120.1 -42.18
23  24.0     Arizona Cardinals  16.0    439.0  ...    9.0  4.4  120.1  15.13
24  25.0        Houston Texans  16.0    403.0  ...   12.0  4.8  121.1  -6.34
25  26.0    Kansas City Chiefs  16.0    416.0  ...   14.0  4.9  128.2 -41.35
26  27.0        Miami Dolphins  16.0    485.0  ...   15.0  4.5  135.4  -6.14
27  28.0  Jacksonville Jaguars  16.0    435.0  ...   23.0  5.1  139.3 -21.95
28  29.0     Carolina Panthers  16.0    445.0  ...   31.0  5.2  143.5 -62.69
29  30.0      Cleveland Browns  16.0    463.0  ...   19.0  5.0  144.7 -37.50
30  31.0   Washington Redskins  16.0    493.0  ...   14.0  4.7  146.2  -6.89
31  32.0    Cincinnati Bengals  16.0    504.0  ...   17.0  4.7  148.9 -12.07
32   NaN              Avg Team   NaN    418.3  ...   14.0  4.3  112.9  11.10
33   NaN          League Total   NaN  13387.0  ...  447.0  4.3  112.9    NaN
34   NaN              Avg Tm/G   NaN     26.1  ...    0.9  4.3  112.9    NaN

[35 rows x 9 columns]
```